# same file, but different file size and sha1_file hash?

Tags: linux, file, ftp, filesystems, sha1

On the same server in different paths the exact same file is stored, but the file sizes are different and the sha1_file hash is too? Why

I download the file from the first path and then upload it to the second path.. Still different file size and different sha1_file hash??

I don't get it?! :-/

Same server, but different paths

Comment: Do files have the same attributes ? (creation date, owner, ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `ftp` for either or both of the transfers, and have a mix of Windows and Linux/Unix systems involved, `ftp` may have "helpfully" converted line endings for you on one of the transfers...

Comment: oh.. I misunderstood you.. Now I get what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. you may check carefully yourself. say, you have file a.pdf and b.pdf, do the following:

```
od a.pdf>a.txt
od b.pdf>b.txt
diff a.txt b.txt
```

and you may find the difference. I think hash codes are independent of the attributes of the files such as modified date.

Comment: Ooops, the size is also different? oh.. maybe I have to know how you have uploaded the file.

Comment: I downloaded it with cuteftp and the same when uploading the file.. But before uploading the file was deleted to ensure the file was not appended or something like that

Comment: try to use "tar" to pack the files. I agree with twalberg's idea. If after trying the diff command you find the difference happens just at each line break, then everything's proved.